# applications of second law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Second law of thermodynamics applies ONLY to thermal engines? Only in cases where we have heat involved? It won't apply to a mechanical machine that works without friction, right? Also will it apply to an electrogenerator? Please elaborate the concept of energy degradation. Does it apply to any energy transformation? Even though we have ideal engines? If yes, how can that be?

Comment: The second law of thermodynamics says that heat, all by itself, flows only from hot to cold. That's the physical definition of temperature. You can apply this to all systems for which heat and temperature are reasonably well defined. That this is so even for electrical machines is not so easy to see until you know about thermoelectric potentials. In practice it is also pretty irrelevant for electric machinery. The loss mechanisms there are limited by economic concerns (it would be too expensive to make these machines better), rather than by thermodynamic limits.

Comment: Note that the ultimate efficiency of a solar cell is limited by thermodynamics. Thermodynamics is incredibly powerful, although often it takes some thought on just how to apply it to a particular system.

Comment: how exactly solar cell is limited by thermodynamics since there is no transfer of heat